# expo eas build fails on dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I have an expo project which I want to build an .aab app so that I can submit it on play store. But when I built it I get an error when it installs dependencies. I think the problem is one of the libraries I am using in my app which is react-native-deck-swiper library. I installed it using --force on my project and I think it is the one giving me an error. The reason why I am saying the problem is the library is because when I remove it from the project, the project builds successfully. So how can I force install on EAS build or make the dependencies install so that my app can work?

Comment: I think Expo not support react-deck-swiper, did you try using expo-dev-client? you can try use other alternative like react-native-deck-swiper, you can check component compatibility on https://reactnative.directory, does it support expo go or not

Comment: actually I made a mistake, the library is react-native-deck-swiper. I tried expo-dev-client and also it fails when it gets to installing dependencies